# Magento 2.4.5- Add required validation for city on checkout page

Tags: checkout-page

Magento 2.4.5- Add  required validation for city on checkout  page

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using overriding LayoutProcessor.

Create di.xml file to override LayoutProcessor and add code below:

```
<type name="Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor">
<plugin name="add-custom-city-validation" type="VendorName\ModuleName\Model\Checkout\LayoutProcessor" sortOrder="10"/>
```

Then after in overrided file put below code to make city field required:

```
namespace VendorName\ModuleName\Model\Checkout;

class LayoutProcessor
{
    public function afterProcess(
    \Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor $subject,
    array  $jsLayout
) {
    $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']['children']
            ['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']['children']['city'] = [
        'required' => true,
    ];
    return $jsLayout;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Magento Default validations in the checkout page for the city

This is the list of these validations :

You can add Magento by default validation or custom Js Validation in the checkout Address Form

List of the Magento default validation rules :

```
validate-grouped-qty

validate-one-checkbox-required-by-name

validate-date-between

validate-dob

max-words

min-words

range-words

letters-with-basic-punc

alphanumeric

letters-only

no-whitespace

zip-range

integer

vinUS

dateITA

dateNL

time

time12h

phoneUS

phoneUK

mobileUK

stripped-min-length

email2

url2

credit-card-types

ipv4

ipv6

pattern

allow-container-className
```

You can also use this link for more details "

https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/frontend-core/guide/validations/rule-list/

If you need more help, you can ping me again